# Ajax request not responding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do a ajax request by clicking a span element.

Here the HTML of the span:

```
<span class="fake-link do-delete" data-id="'. $delid .'">Delete</span>
```

Here is my jQuery ajax request:

```
$(".do-delete").click(function() {

        var item = $(this).attr("data-id");

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "../assets/includes/ajax/delete-item.php",
            data: item,
            cache: true,

            success: function(data) {

                $(".test").append(data);

                // alert("De categorie met zijn respectievelijke onderdelen zijn verwijdert.");

            }

        });

    });
```

Here is my current PHP, to catch the data send by ajax:

```
if (isset($_POST['item'])) {

        $id = $_POST['item'];

        echo 'test';

}
```

But the test isn't coming through, so the item isn't posted...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the network tab of your developer tool. Perhaps you got wrong destination location or a typo.

Comment: Your main problem is that you don't want to debug your code. About this code problem: I suspect it should be `data: { 'item': item },`

Comment: Correcting my first comment: I guess @Regent is right. `data` needs to be valid json and what you wrote there is not. try: `data: {'item': item}`. You always need a key in json

Comment: @regent: Yes, that was the problem:) thanks

Comment: Why did you use span `<span class="fake-link do-delete" data-id="'. $delid .'">Delete</span>`  ?

Comment: @serjoscha to be honest, it has nothing to do with JSON. You pass JavaScript's `Object`, which will be transformed into query string.

Comment: Because it couldn't be a real link as it would redirect the page, and I need to give the user a warning if they were to delete the item if the item had categories linked to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` should be `data: {'item' : item}`

```
$(".do-delete").click(function() {

        var item = $(this).attr("data-id");

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "../assets/includes/ajax/delete-item.php",
            data: {'item' : item},
            cache: true,

            success: function(data) {

                $(".test").append(data);

                // alert("De categorie met zijn respectievelijke onderdelen zijn verwijdert.");

            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: I will, just a few minutes more :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are passing wrong parameters to ajax call, you want to pass data as **JSON** object, so instead of `data: item,`, write `data: {'item': item},`

NOTE: also be sure to be opened developer tools->network tab, in most cases it will let you know where the problem is.